# How to write a Twitter api request to a file in ruby

Tags: ruby, twitter

Excuse me if this is obvious, I only have about 5 days of experience in ruby. I am trying to write the top 10 trending topics on Twitter to a json file. The API request is a GET request to https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json. My code is

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require "JSON"

uri = URI.parse("https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json")

File.open("test.json", "w") do |f|
  f.write(Net::HTTP.get(uri.host, uri.port))
end
```

Its giving me an error

```
D:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1668:in 'initialize': undefined method 'empty?' for 443:Fixnum (NoMethodError) from 
D:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1787:in 'intialize' from 
D:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1081:in 'new' from D:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1081:in 'request_get' from 
D:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:389:in 'block in get_response' from 
D:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in 'start' from 
D:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:388:in 'get_response' from 
D:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:370:in 'get' from test:8:in 'block in (main)'
```

Any help on this would be great

Edit:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/%3Awoeid is all the info on the API call I am using if I missed providing any important info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to Net::HTTP.get is incorrect, it expects (host, path) instead of (host, port):

```
f.write(Net::HTTP.get(uri.host, uri.path))
```

The get method tries to treat what you passed in as a string, which is what causes the exception you see.

You can also write

```
f.write(Net::HTTP.get(uri.host, uri.path, uri.port))
```

To make it use https, but this leads to an empty response (for some reason twitter doesn't like https?)

By the way api v1 is deprecated, I recommend moving to the v1.1 equivalent request: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/trends/place

Comment: Might also be worth noting that the OP was getting an exception because Net::HTTP was calling [String#empty?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-empty-3F) on a Fixnum, and the port number is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned earlier,

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require "JSON"

uri = URI.parse("https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json")  

File.open("test.json", "w") do |f|
   f.write(Net::HTTP.get(uri.host, uri.path)) 
end
```

should work.

Making it readable, however, is a much harder task.